# Recuperar un valor hidden en html

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

Tengo un atributo hidden, que meto a través de un método java:

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" th:value="${url}" />
```

Y quiero meter un input de tipo `text` cuyo valor sera el valor que hay en el hidden "url"

```
<input type="text" id= "textUrl" name="url" th:value="${url}" readonly="readonly" style="visibility:visible;"/>
```

Pero me da problemas, ya que nunca muestra el valor URL si no que muestra un cuadro de texto siempre vacío. Supongo que el problema estará en la forma de pasarle el valor pero no lo veo...

Comment: ¿Ambos valores están en la misma página y fragmento de jsp, no pertenecen a distintos jsps que se cargan de diversa manera? Por favor muestra todo lo necesario para reproducir tu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si el campo hidden funciona correctamente, el problema esta cuando se monta la pagina, el valor  `${url}` está vacío y lo pone en `textUrl`, por eso tienes el texto blanco, despues cambia, pero no se actualiza.

Lo que yo haría es un evento para que cuando se actualice el valor del campo hidden, se actualice tambien el otro:

```
$( "#url" ).change(function() {
  $("#textUrl").val($("#url").val());
});
```

Mira [este ejemplo en fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/duwzpevn/) con algo parecido pero usando `keyup` para hacer el campo de mostrar contraseña, a medida que vas escribiendo en el `input type="password"` se actualiza el `input type="text"`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jordi, era justamente eso, no se recargaba la página por tanto el valor url nunca cambiaba!

Comment: @cucurril mientras que esta es una manera de resolver el problema, al saber la causa del mismo pueden surgir nuevas soluciones que te hagan comprender lo que realmente sucede y cómo evitar caer en ello.